# WordPress Force https On The Whole Website Without A Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, http, https

Currently I forced the https on the whole website by going to Settings -> General and changed:
WordPress Address (URL) & Site Address (URL) from http://mywebsite.org to https://mywebsite.org and it works like a charm.

BUT if the user request a url directly over the "http" protocol the user can access it.

**I want the user if try to access any page over "http" protocol  to redirected or something else to the same location but on the "https" protocol.**

*NOTE: I don't want to edit the .htaccess file I want to put the code specifically in the functions.php file of my active theme.*

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put this code in .htacess file at top

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.org/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you didn't read the note in the question.

Comment: If you redirect http to https then it will be theme specific,And when change your theme then this redirect will fail

Comment: I know that, but I need to put it in functions.php file and because of that I asked my question. Thank you.